# Wrap range of items of ngFor?

Tags: angular

I'd like to wrap a range of elements during an `ngFor`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-my7it8

This outputs html like:

```
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
<p>fourth</p>
```

And I'd like for it to output:

```
<p>first</p>
<div>
    <p>second</p>
    <p>third</p>
</div>
<p>fourth</p>
```

Ideally have this happen based upon a flag. In english it'd be "if a flag is true, open new div. Append items until flag is false."

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of links; let i = index;">
    <div *ngIf="i % 2 !== 0">
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>
    <p *ngIf="i % 2 === 0">{{item.name}}</p>
</ng-container>
```

You can obviously tweak the `*ngIf` to check a different condition.

Comment: I wonder how it should return output where two items are located in one div

Comment: Exactly. The trick of this is wrapping the two divs. That's what I'm stuck on.